# Does the Guid (Folder name inside Config cache ) changes in SharePoint 2010 daily?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, timer-service

Does the Guid (Folder name inside Config cache) changes in SharePoint 2010 daily?

I have a strange issue, at 10 AM the timer service crashed as it couldn't find\create the folder inside the config cache folder with Guid ID.

From the ULS logs, I searche for the GUID which it tries to create the folder, I create it manually and cache will be populated inside that folder.

Timer service runs with FARM account which is part of Admin group. Antivirus exceptions are in place as well.